Are finite simplicial submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$ locally flat?
Let $X \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be a compact topological manifold of dimension $k < n$ without boundary.
We assume that there exists a finite simplicial complex $K$ of simplices within $\mathbb R^n$ such that $X$ is the union of those simplices.
Different authors will call $X$ a "simplicial" or "polyhedral" submanifold.
We say that $X$ is topologically locally flat if for every $x \in X$ there exists an open neighborhood $U \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and a homeomorphism $\phi : U \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ such that $\phi(X \cap U) = \mathbb R^k \subseteq \mathbb R^n$.
Under what conditions is $X$ topologically locally flat?
If your imagination is three-dimensional, then it seems intuitive that you can always flatten a submanifold. In fact, you would even suspect that the flattening can locally look like an explicit piecewise linear homotopy.
What is a counter example of small dimension where $X$ is not locally flat, if any?

Consider a cone in $R^4$  over a nontrivial polygonal knot in $R^3$. This is the most standard example.

@MoisheKohan Thank you. That is a $2$-manifold in $R^4$. Are there examples where $X$ has codimension $1$?

In which category? Do you want to have a PL homeomorphism or a topological homeomorphism? And you should edit your question accordingly.
